# Shortcut to add files into local sql database

Tags: powershell, shortcut

I would like to be able to right click on a file(s) and "send-to" a local MSSQL database. The details are that I would like to store the file contents in "contents" column and the file name in the "filename" column ... how novel :)

*In most cases the file contents is HTML.

It seems like it should be possible through windows shell/SQL Shell using a shortcut to a command in the "shell:sendto" folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null  

$Server1 = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") 'SQLSERVER'  
$Server1.databases["DB"].tables["Table"].rowcount  
$RowCount = $server1.databases["DB"].tables["Table"].rowcount.ToString()  

$TotalRecords = [int]$RowCount  

$wc = New-Object system.net.WebClient  
$url = ""  

$files = @(Get-ChildItem c:\test\*.*)  

"Number of files $($files.length)"  
# Errors out when no files are found  
if($files.length -lt 1) { return }  

foreach($file1 in $files) { 
    # $txt = Get-Content($file1)  
    # $txt = $txt.Replace("'", "''")  
    # Write-Host $file1.name + "  - - " + $Txt  

    $url1 =  $url + $file1  
    Write-Host("URL is " + $url1)  

    $webpage = $wc.DownloadData($url1)  
    $string = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($webpage)  
    $string = $string.Replace("'", "''")  

Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance SERVER -Query "Insert into DATABASE.dbo.Table(text,filename) Values ('$string','$file1')"}
```